# Not able to setup connection to MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, connection

I am new to MySql and trying to setup a connection.
I have provided the below details:
ConnectionName: RefferBuddy
ConnectionMethod : Standard(TCP/IP)
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port : 3306
username : root
password: root

Now when I click on Test Connection, I get the error "Failed to connect to MySql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root".

Can some one help me on this.

Also, I have installed mysql workbench. Do we need to install mysql server also?
Thank You.

Comment: try to change the 127.0.0.1 and put **localhost**

Comment: Yes, you need to install mysql server too. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows7

Answer (score 0):

How was the database created?

One of the methods i use to create the database is with Docker (https://www.docker.com/).

Once you download Docker, you can create a Database with the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
# use version 3 of the docker compose syntax
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    # use a default image
    image: mysql:5.7

    # Port mapping 
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

    # the mysql image uses these to create database and users
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Refferbuddy
      MYSQL_USER: Refferbuddy
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
```

After the file is ready, execute the following command to create the database:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now you can connect to it with MySQL workbech with the following connection:

```
ConnectionName: RefferBuddy
ConnectionMethod : Standard(TCP/IP)
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port : 3306
username : Refferbuddy
password: root
```

More information here: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/